# Use a later version of JavaMail in JBoss 4.2.3

Tags: jboss, classloader, jakarta-mail

What is the best way to use a later version of JavaMail than the one bundled with 4.2.3 (which seems to be 1.4 or 1.4.1). We need a feature only introduced in 1.4.4 for use in server-side code. One option is to simply upgrade the jar in the JBoss server/lib directory, but is there a way to get it to work appropriately with JBoss's classloader infrastructure to bundle the later version in the `.ear`? This will avoid regression testing JBoss with a new library in the server/lib.